# --harmony flag in Node.js 0.12 throws SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

So I wrote the following:

**index.js**

```
let x = 31

console.log(x)
```

And tried testing it with the `--harmony` flag:

```
alex@alex-K43U:~/node/es6$ node --harmony index.js
```

But I get an error:

```
/home/alex/node/es6/index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { let x = 31
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: Illegal let declaration outside extended mode
```

What am I doing wrong? I already updated to node `0.12.1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable *strict mode* in order to use `let`.

You can either:

```
"use strict"
let x = 31
console.log(x)
```

Or:

```
node --harmony --use_strict index.js
```

Then it works as expected:

```
victor@ubuntu:~/Documents$ node --harmony --use_strict index.js
31
```